# widget is only updated at the end of the for loop. I need it to be updated inside the for loop incrementally

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

How can I use this "for loop" bellow to have the window updated immediatly. Sleep(5) is only to see if the items are filled instantly

I am using Qt in a simple " class MainWindow : public QMainWindow" with one button and one plainTextEdit and one textEdit

```cpp
for (int i=0; i < 10 ; i++ )
{
    sentFrame = "toto"+i;
    ui->alarmSent->addItem(sentFrame.toHex()); // filled at the end of for loop
    ui->sentTest->insertPlainText(sentFrame.toHex()); // filled at the end of for loop
    sleep(5);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not use the sleep method in the GUI because it blocks for a long time the eventloop where the GUI lives, a workaround is to use `QTimer::singleShot()` + `QEventLoop`:

```cpp
for (int i=0; i < 10 ; i++ )
{
    sentFrame = "toto"+i;
    ui->alarmSent->addItem(sentFrame.toHex()); 
    ui->sentTest->insertPlainText(sentFrame.toHex()); 
    QEventLoop loop;
    QTimer::singleShot(5*1000, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    loop.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all!!!  It does wait 5 seconds with your methode i can see it in qDebug consol but it dosn't display it instantly on the GUI so it doesn't solve my probleme. I still don't understand why GUI doesn't refresh instantly at each increment.

Comment: @smawell I think you have another mistake since I have tested my answer. On the other GUI lives in an event loop, that is, there is a loop that allows the GUI to perform several actions: read user events such as mouse, keyboard, etc. read OS events such as maximize, minimize, etc. and the repaint but when using sleep does not allow the eventloop to run.

Comment: @smawell [cont.] For example to understand you try to change the size of the window when the loop is executed with your code, you will see that it will freeze. On the other hand, with my solution, no, at least that is what I have tested. So if you want more help then you should provide [mcve]